# will Microsoft Typescript be obsolete when browsers directly support ECMAScript 6 based javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

we are currently using Microsoft TypeScript in our project. I came to know that Microsoft TypeScript is following ECMAScript 6 standards. So when ECMASCript 6 is finalized and released and browsers natively supports javascript based off of ECMAScript 6, do we need Microsoft TypeScript?

Since TypeScript follows ECMAScript 6 standard, after ECMAScript 6 based javascript is directly supported in browsers, can we still use Typescript without compiling into to native javascript as it will be ultimately supported by browsers?

Comment: Type annotations are not part of ES6

Comment: Whether some technology has a future is largely stargazing and opinionating. We don't know, only the future will tell.

Comment: TypeScript is not the same as ECMAScript6. TypeScript adds classes and interfaces and compile-time type checking to Javascript, which is not part of any ECMAScript standard. TypeScript is just set up to use ECMAScript6 so that it is ready for the future when browsers are more ES6 compatible.  The simple answer to your question is 'yes' if you still want type checking. If you don't care about compile time type checking, then you don't need TypeScript now or in the future.

Comment: as per this link http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/nstieglitz/5-great-features-in-es6-harmony i see ECMAScript 6 too proposed to support classes. am i missing something here?

Comment: The feature set of TypeScript seems to be a superset of ES6 features. Thus, TypeScript has more features than a full ES6 implementation would have. Given this information, I don't understand how you think it could be possible for ES6 to render TypeScript obsolete, since TypeScript has extra features that ES6 does not plan to have. Could clarify your question to more carefully explain how and why you anticipate a subset of TypeScript features to render TypeScript obsolete? Your current level of understanding there may be critical to understanding what you're really asking.

Comment: See "why typescript" http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html#

Answer (score 1):

No, because TypeScript has lots other things which are important (at least for me)

Notable:

- Interfaces
- Types
- Very nice tooling support
- Generics

edit:
And in the future TypeScript will support `async` which will maybe come in ES7 and other features so TS might have some features with downlevel support for older browser!

Comment: when such advanced features are implemented in TS and that TS has to be ultimately compiled into plain javascript. will that compiled javascript will have support for old IE browsers atleast IE 8 or 9.?

Comment: From the looks of it in the current prototype I think older browsers are supported: See generated code: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/60a0a49437eb4fc4d96ef9d4e7d33818222ddea2/tests/baselines/reference/asyncMethod9.js#L14-L32 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/60a0a49437eb4fc4d96ef9d4e7d33818222ddea2/src/lib/tslib.js **BUT** I'm not from the TS team so I can't be sure though :)

Comment: Late to the party, but a lot of the "new" features work in ES5 and not ES3. IE9 has some known bugs with ES5 alone, so it's possible that they may not work correctly. I would definitely *not* count on IE8 support. @AlagesanPalani. For example, `async` (which TypeScript does support now) only works when compiled to ES6.